# Vanilla JS event delegation - dealing with child elements of the target element

Tags: javascript, dom, publish-subscribe, event-delegation

I'm trying to do event delegation in vanilla JS. I have a button inside a container like this

```html
<div id="quiz">
    <button id="game-again" class="game-again">
        <span class="icon-spinner icon"></span>
        <span>Go again</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

And following [David Walsh's nice instructions](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) I'm adding an event handler to an ancestor of the button like so:

```js
this.container.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (e.target && e.target.id == 'game-again') {
        e.stopPropagation();
        self.publish('primo:evento');
    }
});
```

Where `this.container` is the #quiz element. This works half the time, but the rest of the time the target of the click event is one of the spans inside the button, so my event handler isn't called. What's the best way to deal with this situation?

Comment: What browsers do you have to support?

Comment: IE9+ and the main modern ones

Comment: Then you can use `.matches` as long as you get the unprefixed version and use `matches.call(e.target,"#game-again,#game-again *")` - see my answer for more details.

Comment: If you want a more generic implementation of event delegation, with a few handy enhancements that's still vanilla JavaScript, check out [Oxydizr](https://github.com/gburghardt/oxydizr). It uses HTML5 data attributes so you can completely decouple behavior from style: `<button data-action="tasks.remove">X</button>`. And you can pass custom data to each of your action handlers taken from the `data-action-params` HTML5 data attribute.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Alternate Solution:**

[MDN: Pointer events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Add a class to all nested child elements (`.pointer-none`)

```css
.pointer-none {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Your mark-up becomes

```html
<div id="quiz">
    <button id="game-again" class="game-again">
        <span class="icon-spinner icon pointer-none"></span>
        <span class="pointer-none">Go again</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

With the pointer set to none, the click event wouldn't fire on those elements.

https://css-tricks.com/slightly-careful-sub-elements-clickable-things/

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48683414/

Answer (score 46):

#### Newer browsers

Newer browsers support [`.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches):

```
this.container.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (e.target.matches('#game-again,#game-again *')) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        self.publish('primo:evento');
    }
});
```

You can get the unprefixed version with

```
var matches = document.body.matchesSelector || document.body.webkitMatchesSelector || document.body.mozMatchesSelector || document.body.msMatchesSelector || document.body.webkitMatchesSelector
```

And then use `.apply` for more browsers (Still IE9+).

#### Older browsers

Assuming you have to support older browsers, you can walk up the DOM:

```
function hasInParents(el,id){
    if(el.id === id) return true; // the element
    if(el.parentNode) return hasInParents(el.parentNode,id); // a parent
    return false; // not the element nor its parents
}
```

However, this will climb the whole dom, and you want to stop at the delegation target:

```
function hasInParentsUntil(el,id,limit){
    if(el.id === id) return true; // the element
    if(el === limit) return false;
    if(element.parentNode) return hasInParents(el.parentNode,id); // a parent
    return false; // not the element nor its parents
}
```

Which, would make your code:

```
this.container.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (hasInParentsUntil(e.target,'game-again',container)) { // container should be 
        e.stopPropagation();                                  // available for this
        self.publish('primo:evento');
    }
});
```

Comment: You're welcome, let me know how it works out for you and if you have any more questions about the code and how it works.

Comment: Thanks, so I got the unprefixed version as you suggested, and made my condition "if (matches.apply(e.target, ['#game-again,#game-again *']))" and works fine.

Comment: Tried using .matches which was fun ... just seems easier to use an identifier like a data attribute instead.

Comment: You've entered `document.body.matchesSelector` twice in your example.

Comment: Why do answers like this get accepted. The way this is structured is very confusing. Don't use code like: ``self.publish('primo:evento');`` in your examples and if you mention something like the unprefixed versions you should give an example of using that as well. On top of that you mention that you can use ``.apply`` and you don't include an example of that either. Very messy.

Comment: @Tomas the answer is written to *answer the question*. It is expected that readers are able to use their own critical thinking skills to determine which parts of the answer are relevant to their own needs. If you think that a better answer could be written, I encourage you to do so.

Comment: How exactly does the * factor into `e.target.matches("#game-again *")`? I only understand that it allows for matching parent elements with that id. Where can I read more about this?