# How are the html and js codes separated from each other?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function show() {
    var todos = get_todos();

    var html = '<ul>';
    for(var i=0; i<todos.length; i++) {
        html += '<li>' + todos[i] + ' <button class="remove" id="' + i  + '">Delete</button></li>';
    };
    html += '</ul>';

    document.getElementById('todos').innerHTML = html;

    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
    for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', remove);
    };
}
```

In this code, I want to separate the 'ul and li' structure on the html page. Could you help me?

Comment: The question is too vague. You should consider adding more details to it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create the `ul` and `li` in a separate file that has .html extension?

Comment: Yeap a seperate .html page

Comment: I would like to find out that this example html codes are separate javascript codes from https://code-maven.com/todo-in-html-and-javascript page. Can not do it?

Comment: I think what you're looking for here is a templating engine, which allows you to load bits of HTML code in JavaScript so you can dynamically create HTML elements without hardcoding the HTML markup into your JavaScript code. Is that it? If so, look up Handlebars.js, or just google "javascript templating"

Comment: You are definately looking for `<script src="..." type="text/javascript"></script>`. Here you go: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-javascript-to-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is want something you can do, if you want some code to `html`

You can refer the js from html using `script tag` **check the plunker below**

You need that script too, because **you are adding li dynamically using script**

Eg: **`<script src = "script.js"></script>`**

**Steps:**

- I have taken a html and created a `ul` element.
- Created a script which appends `li` to the `ul` element.
- Added a reference to that script using the `script tag`

```js
function show() {
  var ul = document.getElementById('list');
  var html = '';
  var todos = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
  for(var i=0; i<todos.length; i++) {
     var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todos[i]));
    ul.appendChild(li);
  };
  ul.append(html);
     var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
    for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', remove);
    };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<ul id="list">
</ul>
<p id="demo" onClick="show()">Click ME</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**Here is a working demo for the same**](https://plnkr.co/edit/WLeiTeRs4MnUENRKFj8J?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is an HTML template that you can re-use and keep separate from your JS code. A popular templating engine is [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com).

The steps to get this to work are:

- Write a template in your HTML. Using a hidden `<div>` is one way to do it.
- Load the template contents in your JS code.
- Compile the template to get a function which will accepts data and returns HTML.
- Call that function with your data, assign the result to an existing container element.
- Use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) to attach behavior to active elements like buttons.

Together this will look like this:

```js
var todoListSource = document.getElementById("todoList").innerHTML;
var todoList = Handlebars.compile(todoListSource);

var items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"];

var todoContainer = document.getElementById("todo");
todoContainer.innerHTML = todoList(items);


// event delegation - use the same event handler for all buttons
// modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24117490/18771
todoContainer.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (!e.target.matches('.deleteTodo')) return;

    e.stopPropagation();
    var li = e.target.parentElement;
    li.parentElement.removeChild(li);
});
```

```css
.template {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<div id="todo"></div>

<div class="template" id="todoList">
  <ul>
    {{#each .}}
    <li>
      <span>{{.}}</span>
      <button class="deleteTodo">delete</button>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Using jQuery you can simplify the JS part.

```js
var todoList = Handlebars.compile($("#todoList").html());

var items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"];

$("#todo").html(todoList(items));

// event delegation - use the same event handler for all buttons
$("#todo").on('click', '.deleteTodo', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

```css
.template {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="todo"></div>

<div class="template" id="todoList">
  <ul>
    {{#each .}}
    <li>
      <span>{{.}}</span>
      <button class="deleteTodo">delete</button>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
```